# how to verify if download was succeessful in frame

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, iframe

I am giving the customer an `url`. when he clicks in the url, a page is loaded, with the following `iframe`

```
<iframe id="downloadIFrame" style="display: none" src="file_url.csv"></iframe>
```

the file:`"file_url"` is downloaded. while downloading, many things can go wrong(pop-up blocker, customer clicks on cancel, url is corrupt etc).
I want to check that if the download was successful or not

I have tried onload() and

```
    document.getElementById('downloadIFrame').onreadystatechange = MyIframeReadyStateChanged;
        function MyIframeReadyStateChanged()
        {
            if(document.getElementById('downloadIFrame').readyState == 'complete')
            {
                alert('new');
            }
        }
```

these are not working

does anyone have an idea how to do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `iframe` is the equivalent of a `window`.  That means when you do `document.getElementById()` of the `iframe`, you are getting the window and not the document in that window.  So I think you need something like this:

```
document.getElementById('downloadIFrame').document.onreadystatechange = FuncName;
```

and inside the specified function:

```
if(document.getElementById('downloadIFrame').document.readyState == 'complete')
```